# find_package catkin several times

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
let's say I have a catkin package which builds several executables.

Each one of these executables depends on a different set of catkin packages  (i.e. catkin CMake components).

How can I link properly these executables? Is it ok to call `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` several times?

E.g.,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(myproject)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp sensor_msgs)
add_executable(myexec1 myexec1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexec1 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)
add_executable(myexec2 myexec2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexec2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

how about the `include_directories` statements?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308445/find_package-catkin-several-times/) by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How can I link properly these executables? Is it ok to call `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` several times?

No, that won't work (due to caching, CMake may not actually even call `find_package()` again).

A work-around could be to not use `find_package(catkin .. COMPONENTS ..)`, but to `find_package(..)` each of your dependencies separately (so `find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)` and `find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)`) and then manually add the results of those calls to the include and link paths of the respective binaries.

> how about the `include_directories` statements?

CMake supports *per target* properties, such as include and link paths (with either `set_target_properties(..)` or `target_include_directories(..)`). You could use those.

---

But an observation: if the executables are really so different that they don't have (m)any shared dependencies, I would ask myself whether these executables should be hosted by the same package.

Perhaps they should be in a package of their own.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-14**:
Note: your question is more a CMake question than a ROS/Catkin one. Even without any ROS involved you would/could run into the same issues (and your question about per-executable `include_directories(..)` reinforces this).

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2018-11-14**:
Yes, but since of the unique feature of `catkin` seeing the other packages as components of itself (to avoid per-package `find_package` statements) I ran into this question. In a plain CMake project I would find all the libraries I need and then add only the generated variables I need per executable

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2018-11-14**:
To reply to the original observation about splitting the code in multiple packages, I didn't mention that 1) this is no my code 2) I oversimplified the problem to the bare minimum. There are multiple nested CMake subprojects into this package. It is a complex cmake project converted to catkin.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-14**:\

> Yes, but since of the unique feature of `catkin` seeing the other packages as components of itself

as you already comment: this is just convenience. You don't need to use that. A simple `find_package(catkin REQUIRED)` with the rest in their own `find_package(..)` is also fine and will work ok.

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2018-11-14**:
Ok then I will use the `catkin` components only for the shared resources among all binaries and individual ones for the others. Thanks.